# Streaming media server

Tags: javascript, video

I'm wondering if anyone would like to give me some solid advice on how to better organize my main.js file. I have a hunch that I should probably break the file into multiple files and decrease the amount of global variables. Maybe my naming is not so great either? I'm using codekit so I can prepend if that won't screw up my scopes.

[GitHub](https://github.com/adamgedney/AGedneySMS/blob/master/js/main.js)

```
//@codekit-prepend "jquery-1.10.2.min.js"
//@codekit-prepend "jquery.event.special.js"
//@codekit-prepend "jquery.easing.min.js"
//@codekit-prepend "lightbox-2.6.min.js"
//@codekit-prepend "handlebars-v1.1.2.js" 

//Globals
var duration;
var seek_time;
var seek_bar_left;
var seek_bar_right;
var seek_scrub;
var seek_bar_width;
var xPos;
var name;
var cam_toggle;
var mic_toggle;
var rec_toggle;
var fav_toggle;
var mic_index = 0;//0 default mic
var cam_index = 0;//0 default cam
var drag = false;
var play_toggle = false;
var playing = false;
var recording = false;
var connection_open = false;
var current_video;
var current_user;
var user_avatar;
var user_avatar_array = [];
var comments_array = [];
var user_array = [];
var created_array = [];
var new_video = false;


//firebase globals
var db = new Firebase('https://adamgedney.firebaseio.com/');
var video_obj = db.child('/videos');
var comments_obj = db.child('/comments');

// var globalError = function(message){
//         console.log(message, "error mess");
// }
//==========================================callbacks=================================//
var connected = function(success, error){
         console.log(success, error);
        if(success){
                connection_open = true;

                if(recording){
                        flash.startRecording(name,cam_index,mic_index);
                }else{
                        flash.startPlaying(current_video);
                };
        }else{
                connection_open = false;
        }
};

var getDuration = function(dur){
        duration = dur;
};

var seekTime = function(time){
        seek_time = time;

        xPos = (seek_time / duration) * seek_bar_right;

        // scrub position update only when not dragging
        if(!drag){
                $('#seek_bar_scrub').offset({left: seek_bar_left + xPos});
        }

};// seekTime()

//auth callback
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(db, function(error, user){

        if(!error){
                if(user.provider == "github"){
                        current_user = user.displayName;
                        user_avatar = user.avatar_url;
                        login();
                }else if(user.provider == "twitter"){
                        current_user = user.displayName;
                        user_avatar = user.profile_image_url;
                        login();
                }
        }
});

//
//end callbacks
//

//========================Seek Bar drag/drop functionality=========================//
        //mousedown to start drag
        $(document).on('mousedown', '#seek_bar_scrub', function(e){
                drag = true;

                //required to prevent text selection on mouseout of seek_bar
                e.preventDefault();
                moving();
        });

        //mouseup to stop drag
        $(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
                drag = false;
        });

        //drag and setTime
        function moving(){
                $(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
                        var set_time = ((e.pageX - seek_bar_left) / seek_bar_width) * duration;

                        if(drag){

                                $('#seek_bar_scrub').offset({left: e.pageX});

                                //sets scrub time
                                flash.setTime(set_time);

                                //creates a border 
                                if(seek_scrub < seek_bar_left){
                                        $('#seek_bar_scrub').offset({left: seek_bar_left});

                                }else if(seek_scrub > (seek_bar_right  - $('#seek_bar_scrub').width())){
                                        $('#seek_bar_scrub').offset({left: (seek_bar_right - $('#seek_bar_scrub').width())});

                                };
                        };
                });
        };

        //flash ready serves as document ready
        var flashReady = function(){

                //sets init volume to 70
                $('#vol_bar').val(100);

                $(document).on('click', '#play_btn', function(e){

                        play_video();
                });
        };// flashReady()

        //set volume init
        $(document).on('change', function(e){

                var vol = $('#vol_bar').val() / 100;
                        vol = vol.toFixed(1);

                        flash.setVolume(vol);
        });

        function play_video(){
                //handles connect or play/pause toggle
                        if(!playing){
                                flash.stopRecording();
                                flash.connect('rtmp://localhost/SMSServer/');

                                playing = true;
                                recording = false;
                                new_video = false;

                        }else if(playing && !recording && new_video){

                                flash.stopPlaying();
                                flash.connect('rtmp://localhost/SMSServer/');
                                new_video = false;

                        }else if(playing && !new_video){

                                flash.playPause();

                        }

                        //handles image toggle
                        if (!play_toggle){

                                $('#play_btn').attr('src', 'images/pause.png');
                                play_toggle = true;

                        }else{
                                $('#play_btn').attr('src', 'images/play.png');
                                play_toggle = false;
                        }
        };

//---------------------------Templating--------------------------//
init();

function init(){

        $.get('templates/templates.html', function(htmlArg){

                var source = $(htmlArg).find('#logged_out').html();
                var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                // var context = {id: posts._id, title:posts.title, created: posts.created, author: posts.author, category: posts.category, text: posts.text}
                // var html = template(context);

                $('#content').append(template);

                //defaults to hide upon program load
                $('.transport_popup').hide();
                $('.rec_select').hide();
                $('.mic_select').hide();
                $('.cam_select').hide();
                $('.login_popup').hide();
                $('.sub_list').hide();

        });//get()
};//init()

//--------------------On login, $.get logged in state----------------//
$(document).on('click', '#login_gh', function(e){

        //github authentication
        auth.login('github');
});

$(document).on('click', '#login_tw', function(e){

        //github authentication
        auth.login('twitter');
});

        function login(){
                $.get('templates/templates.html', function(htmlArg){

                        var source = $(htmlArg).find('#logged_in').html();
                        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                        // var context = {id: posts._id, title:posts.title, created: posts.created, author: posts.author, category: posts.category, text: posts.text}
                        // var html = template(context);

                        $('#content').empty();
                        $('#content').append(template);

                        //defaults to hide upon program load
                        $('.transport_popup').hide();
                        $('.rec_select').hide();
                        $('.mic_select').hide();
                        $('.cam_select').hide();
                        $('.stop_rec_modal').hide();
                        $('.login_popup').hide();
                        $('.sub_list').hide();


                        seek_bar_width = $('#seek_bar_inner').width();
                        seek_bar_left = Math.floor($('#seek_bar_inner').offset().left);
                        seek_bar_right = seek_bar_left + seek_bar_width;
                        seek_scrub = $('#seek_bar_scrub').offset().left;


                        swfobject.embedSWF(
                    "swf/higley_wigley.swf", "flashContent",
                    "100%", "100%",
                    swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr,
                    flashvars, params, attributes);
                        // JavaScript enabled so display the flashContent div in case it is not replaced with a swf object.
                        swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;");

                        //populates comments & video fields
                        get_comments();
                        get_videos();


                });//get()
        };//login()

//Controls logout
$(document).on('click', '#login_state', function(e){

        if($('#login_state').html() == "Logout"){

                //logs out facebook or twitter
                auth.logout();

                $.get('templates/templates.html', function(htmlArg){

                        var source = $(htmlArg).find('#logged_out').html();
                        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                        // var context = {id: posts._id, title:posts.title, created: posts.created, author: posts.author, category: posts.category, text: posts.text}
                        // var html = template(context);

                        $('#content').empty();
                        $('#content').append(template);

                        //defaults to hide upon program load
                        $('.transport_popup').hide();
                        $('.rec_select').hide();
                        $('.mic_select').hide();
                        $('.cam_select').hide();
                        $('.login_popup').hide();
                        $('.sub_list').hide();

                });//get()
        };// if
});

//-------------Show/hide login dropdown----------------//

var log_toggle = false;

$(document).on('click', '#login_state', function(e){

        if(!log_toggle){
                $('.login_popup').fadeIn();
                log_toggle = true;
        }else{
                $('.login_popup').fadeOut();
                log_toggle = false;
        }
});

//====================Show/Hide mic/cam/rec options=====================//

//camera select popup
$(document).on('click', '#camera_btn', function(e){

        if (!cam_toggle){
                //hides other popups
                $('.mic_select').hide();
                $('.rec_select').hide();
                $('#mic_btn').css('opacity', '1');
                rec_toggle = false;
                mic_toggle = false;

                $('#camera_btn').css('opacity', '.5');
                $('.transport_popup').fadeIn();
                $('.cam_select').fadeIn();

                cam_toggle = true;

                //get and loop through attached cameras
                var cam_list = flash.getCameras();
                $('.cameras').empty();

                for(var i=0; i<cam_list.length; i++){
                        var li = '<li><a id="' + i + '" href="#">' +  cam_list[i].substr(0, 18) + '</a></li>';
                        $('.cameras').append(li);
                }

        }else{
                $('#camera_btn').css('opacity', '1');
                $('.transport_popup').fadeOut();
                $('.cam_select').fadeOut();

                cam_toggle = false;
        }

});

//select and store camera choice
$(document).on('click', '.cameras a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        cam_index = $(this).attr("id");
});

//mic select popup
$(document).on('click', '#mic_btn', function(e){

        if (!mic_toggle){
                //hides other popups
                $('.cam_select').hide();
                $('.rec_select').hide();
                $('#camera_btn').css('opacity', '1');
                cam_toggle = false;
                rec_toggle = false;

                $('#mic_btn').css('opacity', '.5');
                $('.transport_popup').fadeIn();
                $('.mic_select').fadeIn();

                mic_toggle = true;

                //get and loop through attached cameras
                var mic_list = flash.getMicrophones();
                $('.mics').empty();

                for(var j=0; j<mic_list.length; j++){
                        var li = '<li><a id="' + j + '" href="#">' +  mic_list[j].substr(0, 20) + '</a></li>';
                        $('.mics').append(li);
                }


        }else{
                $('#mic_btn').css('opacity', '1');
                $('.transport_popup').fadeOut();
                $('.mic_select').fadeOut();

                mic_toggle = false;
        }

});

//select and store microphone choice
$(document).on('click', '.mics a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        mic_index = $(this).attr("id");
});

//record popup
$(document).on('click', '#rec_btn', function(e){

        if (!rec_toggle){
                //hides other popups
                $('.mic_select').hide();
                $('.cam_select').hide();
                $('#rec_btn').attr('src', 'images/cancel_rec.png');
                $('#rec_btn').attr('title', 'Cancel Recording');
                $('#mic_btn').css('opacity', '1');
                $('#cam_btn').css('opacity', '1');
                cam_toggle = false;
                mic_toggle = false;

                $('.transport_popup').fadeIn();
                $('.rec_select').fadeIn();

                rec_toggle = true;
        }else{
                $('#rec_btn').attr('src', 'images/rec.png');
                $('#rec_btn').attr('title', 'Record A Video');

                $('.transport_popup').fadeOut();
                $('.rec_select').fadeOut();

                rec_toggle = false;
        }

});

//start recording
$(document).on('click', '#start_recording', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        name = $('#name').val();
        var cat = $('#category').val();
        var desc = $('#file_desc').val();

        //opens connection
        flash.stopPlaying();
        flash.connect('rtmp://localhost/SMSServer/');
        recording = true;
        playing = false;

        // $('.poster').fadeOut();
        $('.stop_rec_modal').fadeIn();

        //resets the record modal
        $('#rec_btn').attr('src', 'images/rec.png');
        $('#rec_btn').attr('title', 'Record A Video');
        $('.transport_popup').fadeOut();
        $('.rec_select').fadeOut();
        rec_toggle = false;

        //adds video to database
        video_obj.push({video: name, category: cat, description: desc, author: current_user, created_date: get_datetime()});
});

//stop recording button
$(document).on('click', '#stop_rec', function(e){
        flash.stopRecording();
        $('.stop_rec_modal').hide();


        // $('.poster').fadeIn();

});        

//-------------Favorites button------------//
$(document).on('click', '#fav_btn', function(e){

        if (!fav_toggle){
                $('#fav_btn').attr('src', 'images/star_y.png');
                fav_toggle = true;
        }else{
                $('#fav_btn').attr('src', 'images/star.png');
                fav_toggle = false;
        }

});

//------------Category Dropdown----------------//
var cat_toggle;
var v_toggle;
var f_toggle;

$(document).on('click', '.drop_down', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();


        if($(this).html() == 'My Videos'){

                if(!v_toggle){
                        $('.vid_cats').fadeOut();
                        $('.favorited_vids').fadeOut();
                        f_toggle = false;
                        cat_toggle = false;

                        $('.my_vids').fadeIn();
                        v_toggle = true;
                }else{
                        $('.my_vids').fadeOut();
                        v_toggle = false;
                }

        }else if($(this).html() == 'Favorites'){

                if(!f_toggle){
                        $('.my_vids').fadeOut();
                        $('.vid_cats').fadeOut();
                        cat_toggle = false;
                        v_toggle = false;

                        $('.favorited_vids').fadeIn();
                        f_toggle = true;
                }else{
                        $('.favorited_vids').fadeOut();
                        f_toggle = false;
                }

        }else if($(this).html() == 'Categories'){

                if(!cat_toggle){
                        $('.favorited_vids').fadeOut();
                        $('.my_vids').fadeOut();
                        f_toggle = false;
                        v_toggle = false;

                        $('.vid_cats').fadeIn();
                        cat_toggle = true;
                }else{
                        $('.vid_cats').fadeOut();
                        cat_toggle = false;
                }
        };
});

$(document).on('click', '.sub_list a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.sub_list').fadeOut();
        cat_toggle = false;
        v_toggle = false;
        f_toggle = false;
});

//============================Click Handlers==============================//

        //set comments
        $(document).on('click', '#submit_comment', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                set_comment();

        });

        //select lesson from list & set current video to this value
        $(document).on('click', '.lesson', function(e){

                var this_title = $(this).find('h2').html();
                var this_time = $(this).find('h3').html();
                var this_desc = $(this).find('p').html();

                current_video = this_title + ".flv";
                new_video = true;

                // flash.stopPlaying();
                play_video();
                get_comments();


                render_info(this_title, this_time, this_desc);
        });

//============================Getters/Setters==============================//
        function set_comment(){
                var com = $('#new_comment').val();
                var usr = current_user;
                var d = get_datetime();
                var t = current_video;


                //pushes comment into messages object
                comments_obj.push({user: usr, avatar: user_avatar, comment: com, created: d, title: t});

                //resets comment form
                $('#new_comment').val('');

                //gets comments and appends to comment list
                get_comments();
        };

        //retrieve comments when there is a new one
        //store in the comments_array
        function get_comments(){
                $('.comments_wrapper').empty();

                comments_obj.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
                    console.log(snapshot.val().title, "comment in db");

                    var comments = snapshot.val().comment;
                    var users = snapshot.val().user;
                    var created = snapshot.val().created;
                    var avatar = snapshot.val().avatar;

                    //empties arrays
                          comments_array = [];
                          user_array = [];
                          created_array = [];
                          user_avatar_array = [];

                    if(snapshot.val().title == current_video){

                                  //pushes result strings into arrays
                                  comments_array.push(comments);
                                  user_array.push(users);
                                  created_array.push(created);
                                  user_avatar_array.push(avatar);


                                  render_comments();
                        };
                });
        }; //get_comments()

        function get_videos(){

                video_obj.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {

                           var video_array = [];
                    video_array.push(snapshot.val());

                          render_videos(video_array);
                });
        }; //get_comments()

        function get_datetime(){
                // datetime on 12 hr clock
                var d = new Date();
                var        day = d.getDay();
                var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                var year = d.getFullYear();
                var hour = d.getHours();
                var minutes = d.getMinutes();
                var time;
                if(hour > 12){
                        hour = hour - 12;
                        time = hour + ":" + minutes;

                        time += "pm";
                }

                return month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " " + time;
        };


//============================Renderers==============================//
        function render_videos(video_array){

                  for (var l=0;l<video_array.length;l++){

                          var s = '<div class="lesson">';
                                s += '<img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="video thumbnail"/>';
                                s += '<h2>' + video_array[l].video + '</h2>';
                                s += '<h3>' + video_array[l].created_date + '</h3>';
                                s += '<p>' + video_array[l].description + '</p>';
                                s += '</div><!-- ./lesson-->';                        

                          $('.lessons_container').append(s);
                };// for
        };

        function render_comments(){

                  for (var k=0;k<comments_array.length;k++){

                          var s = '<div class="comment">';
                                  s += '<a href="' + user_avatar_array[k] + '" data-lightbox="avatar id" ><img src="' + user_avatar_array[k] + '" alt="user avatar" /></a>';
                                  s += '<h2>' + user_array[k] + '</h2>';
                                  s += '<h3>' + created_array[k] + '</h3>';
                                  s += '<p>' + comments_array[k] + '</p>';
                                s += '</div><!-- /.comment-->';                                        

                          $('.comments_wrapper').append(s);
                };// for
        };

        function render_info(title, time, desc){
                $('.desc').empty();

                var s = '<div class="title_wrapper">';
                        s += '<h1>' + title + '</h1>';
                        s += '<p class="time">' + time + '</p>';
                        s += '</div><!-- /.title_wrapper-->';
                        s += '<p class="desc_copy">' + desc + '</p>';
                        s += '<div class="desc_gallery">';
                        s += '<a href="images/poster.jpg" data-lightbox="movie screenshots"><img src="images/shot.jpg" alt="movie screenshot 1"/></a>';
                        s += '<a href="images/poster.jpg" data-lightbox="movie screenshots"><img src="images/shot.jpg" alt="movie screenshot 2"/></a>';
                        s += '</div><!-- /.desc_gallery-->';

                $('.desc').append(s);
        };
```

Comment: please fix your indentation, it's horrific and makes reading it difficult especially in Post formatting.  I already removed the white space.  I would get rid of it if it is in your code.  if you did it to separate the blocks in this post you should use `---`   with a new line before and after, this will give you a separator line in the post

Comment: Things like `$('#rec_btn').attr('src', 'images/cancel_rec.png');
                $('#rec_btn').attr('title', 'Cancel Recording');` should usually be chained and written `$('#rec_btn').attr('src', 'images/cancel_rec.png').attr('title', 'Cancel Recording');`

Comment: Also I'd recommend creating a namespace and putting all those globals in your namespace object

Answer (score 2):

Two random thoughts:

1. In the *Category Dropdown* part the `$(this).html()` could be extracted out to a named local variable.
2. The following code is duplicated, it could be extracted out a separate function:

   ```
   $('.transport_popup').hide();
   $('.rec_select').hide();
   $('.mic_select').hide();
   $('.cam_select').hide();
   ```

Comment: you could also write it `$('.transport_popup, .rec_select, .mic_select, .cam_select').hide()` and underscores in css names is poor style